# How to get multiple values from a template and update multiple rows in a table? Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm fairly new to Django and Python. I have a inventory management website. I am trying to update multiple values in a database. User should be able to input updated stock values and it should update each item's stock value which has been submitted.
[Image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjhO6.png)

I tried "item[{{item.id}}]" to create a list but i'm not sure how to use this list or how to update multiple rows. My guess is that I need to gather all the values and keys from the template and in POST run a loop and update the relavant rows by ID.

template

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for item in items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.description}}</td>
      <td>{{item.buyprice}}</td>
      <td>{{item.sellprice}}</td>
      <td><input type="number" value="{{item.instock}}" name="item[{{item.id}}]"></td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

view

```
def stockUpd(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        items = Item.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        context = {
        'items':items
        }
        return render(request,'stock/stockupd.html',context);
    #if request.method == 'POST':
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do

```
<input type="number" value="{{item.instock}}" name="item_{{item.id}}">
```

Then

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    data = request.POST.dict()
    data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)
    for i in data.items():
        obj = Item.objects.get(id=i[0].split("_")[1])
        if not str(obj.instock) == str(i[1]): #here check int or char datatype since 1 not equal "1"
            obj.instock = i[1]
            obj.save()
```

Comment: Got this error. Had to cut somethings hope that is ok.Traceback:

  41.             response = get_response(request)

  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\*\Desktop\*\views.py" in stockUpd
  23.             split=i[0].split("_")[1]

Exception Type: IndexError at /stock/upd/
Exception Value: list index out of range

Comment: Check `print request.POST`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean.POST
Variable Value
csrfmiddlewaretoken 
'xkBwwbjDT2DPphZHUpr3m5adlXthqpFNoksByMFgsoqzN7inJedkyVP2cYwExrex'
item_2 
'23'
item_14 
'100'

Comment: do `data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')` on top of for loop.

Comment: Now getting: 'generator' object has no attribute 'pop'

Comment: Updated the answer