# update multiple django id's at once

Tags: python, django

I have a django html page where I have multiple records total 3 colomns(id,P_350,P_450) and I want to update at once when I click submit button.

It is working fine when I was updating one by one but I wanted to update multiple records so that I added a loop "for id in ids:" in front to access multiple id's; but somehow I did not able to make it work.

My questions is:

- Should I use also getlist method for the other P_350 and P_450
- Am I doing correct by looping ids.If not how can I do that ?

Here is my view.py file:

```
    ids = request.POST.getlist("id")
    P_350 = request.POST["P_350"]
    P_450 = request.POST["P_450"]
    for id in ids:
        fp_item = fp.objects.get(id=id)
        items=[P_350,P_450]
        for index, w in enumerate(items):
            if index == 0:
                if len(w) > 1:
                    fp_item.P_350 = w
                    fp_item.save()
            elif index == 1:
                if len(w) > 1:
                    fp_item.P_450 = w
                    fp_item.save()
```

Here is my html file input section:

```
<td style="display:none;">
<input name="id" type="text" value={{ field.id }} >
</td>
<td width="650">
{{ field.FP_Item }}
</td>
{% if field.P_350|length == 0 %}
<td style="display:none;">
{% else %}
<td>
{% endif %}
<input name="P_350" type="text" value={{ field.P_350 }} >
</td>
{% if field.P_450|length == 0 %}
<td style="display:none;">
{% else %}
<td>
{% endif %}
<input name="P_450" type="text" value={{ field.P_450 }} >
</td>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) to query for all the items at once, instead of looping over the ids

```
ids = request.POST.getlist("id")
qs = fp.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

You can use the queryset's [`.update` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#update) to update all items in the queryset at once.

```
P_350 = request.POST["P_350"]
P_450 = request.POST["P_450"]

updates = {}
if len(P_350) > 1:
    updates['P_350'] = P_350
if len(P_450) > 1:
    updates['P_450'] = P_450

if updates:
    qs.update(**updates)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.This approach way better :)  Although I have a problem where it's updating the different id's with the same value of P_350. Lets assume that I entered for id 1  --  P_350 =" try_1"   id 2  -- P_350 = "try_2"   when I click submit then it become both id's  the same "try_2" value.  How can we overcome this situation

Comment: Should I use something similar like this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559164/how-to-get-multiple-values-from-a-template-and-update-multiple-rows-in-a-table       Do I need to use variable name stating the id as well ?