# queryset update with multiple variables duplicate

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am having an issue that I have database updated with the same value as for both id's even though they are different as per my example below:
Lets assume that I entered as input for id 1 -- P_350 =" try_1" id 2 -- P_350 = "try_2" when I click submit then it become both id's the same "try_2" value.
What you suggest to overcome this situation.

- Should I need to use variable input name including the id in front of the input name ?
- Or any easier method ?

I have the below view.py for my database updates:

```
ids = request.POST.getlist("id")
qs = fp.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

P_350 = request.POST["P_350"]
P_450 = request.POST["P_450"]

updates = {}
if len(P_350) > 1:
    updates['P_350'] = P_350
if len(P_450) > 1:
    updates['P_450'] = P_450

if updates:
    qs.update(**updates)
```

Here is my html file input section:

```
<td style="display:none;">
<input name="id" type="text" value={{ field.id }} >
</td>
<td width="650">
{{ field.FP_Item }}
</td>
{% if field.P_350|length == 0 %}
<td style="display:none;">
{% else %}
<td>
{% endif %}
<input name="P_350" type="text" value={{ field.P_350 }} >
</td>
{% if field.P_450|length == 0 %}
<td style="display:none;">
{% else %}
<td>
{% endif %}
<input name="P_450" type="text" value={{ field.P_450 }} >
</td>
```

Comment: see the values in the console

Answer (score 1):

**Wrong logic**

If you putting different value at same input P_350 this will get the last value you place when it reaches the backend, you probabily should put your first value in P_350 and the second in P_450.

In your example  you only manipulate P_350 2 times... so P_450 will never be updated because he dont have a new value.

If you have multiple inputs related with P_350, you should first get all first and then send to backend (AJAX like async) or place multiple P_350 with different names and handle it at backend when save each one

https://medium.com/@taranjeet/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0

Comment: Hımm, so I would need something similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559164/how-to-get-multiple-values-from-a-template-and-update-multiple-rows-in-a-table  Item id in front of the name

Comment: Do you have any sample to direct me I have no idea about ajax one but I think changing the name would be easier

Comment: https://medium.com/@taranjeet/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0

Comment: complicated but very nice example :)