# How to get multiple values from a template and update multiple fields in a rows of thesame table in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am working on a result processing website and I've been trying to update multiple fields in each row of table. User should be able to input updated CA Score and EXAM Score values and it should update each student's CA Score and EXAM Score values which has been submitted.  [image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRmog.png)

Someone ask same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559164/how-to-get-multiple-values-from-a-template-and-update-multiple-rows-in-a-table) trying to update a single field. I tried to work with the solution provided there but was unable to make it suit my need

template

```
<form action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
{% for student in students %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ student.id_number }}</td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" value="{{ student.ca }}" name="student_{{ student.id }}">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input type="number" value="{{ student.exam }}" name="student_{{ student.id }}">
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
<tr>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

view

```
def add_score_for(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        students = TakenCourse.objects.filter(course__allocated_course__lecturer__pk=request.user.id).filter(course__id=id)
        context = { "students":students}
        return render(request, 'result/add_score_for.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.dict()
        data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)
        for i in data.items():
            obj = TakenCourse.objects.get(id=i[0].split("_")[1])
            if not str(obj.ca) == str(i[1]): # if i do i[2] trying to get for exams it raise 'tuple index out of range'
                obj.ca = i[1]
                obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved my problem, don't know if its the best way to do it but it did solve my issue

views

```
@lecturer_required 
def add_score_for(request, id):
    current_semester = Semester.objects.get(is_current_semester=True)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        ...
        return render(request, 'result/add_score_for.html', context)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        ids = ()
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None) # remove csrf_token
        for key in data.keys():
            ids = ids + (str(key),)      # gather all the all students id (i.e the keys) in a tuple
        for s in range(0,len(ids)):      # iterate over the list of student ids gathered above
            score = data.getlist(ids[s]) # get list of score for current student in the loop
            ca = score[0]                # subscript the list to get the fisrt value > ca score
            exam = score[1]              # do thesame for exam score
            obj = TakenCourse.objects.get(student__pk=ids[s]) # get the current student data
            obj.ca = ca # set current student ca score
            obj.exam = exam # set current student exam score
            obj.total = obj.get_total(ca=ca,exam=exam)
            obj.grade = obj.get_grade(ca=ca,exam=exam)
            obj.comment = obj.get_comment(obj.grade)
            obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('add_score_for', kwargs={'id': id}))
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('add_score_for', kwargs={'id': id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain Django you would solve this using Formsets:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

This will generate the markup (or allow you to generate the markup) you need to update multiple students which will then be updated on submit. It also allows to add the entries (you can disable this feature).

Comment: thanks for replying, I just try working with formset but i returns a single row instead of all the available rows in the model.

Comment: you need to pass all rows as `initial` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset

Comment: Thank you so much for the help but i resolved the problem using the above approach