# Django - Forms: 'module' object is not callable error

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf

I am trying to update several rows in my table. Same with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559164/how-to-get-multiple-values-from-a-template-and-update-multiple-rows-in-a-table). I modified codes for my project and trying to solve it since a few days but it doesn't work for me. Firstly, i am show all existing rows in html page in a form. And if it is POST request then trying to save into db. I have 2 error here. 1. If i use `return render_to_response('module.html',{'modules' : modules})` it is showing data in html page like i want but when click to save button, it give below error on POST request:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

2. If i use `return render(request, 'module.html',{'modules' : modules})`, it is not even showing data and just give below error on GET request :

   ```
   Environment:

   Request Method: GET
   Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/module/nav-tab/new

   Django Version: 2.1.3
   Python Version: 3.7.1
   Installed Applications:
   ['MyApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles']
   Installed Middleware:
   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

   Traceback:
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
   34.response = get_response(request)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
   126.response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
   124.response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
   142.response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
   142.response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

   File "/Users/cem/Documents/Projects/Python/Web/FirstApp/MyApp/views.py" in addmodule
   157.return render(request,template_name, args)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
   36.content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
   62.return template.render(context, request)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
   61.return self.template.render(context)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
   169.with context.bind_template(self):

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py" in __enter__
   112.return next(self.gen)

   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in bind_template
   246.updates.update(processor(self.request))

   Exception Type: TypeError at /module/nav-tab/new
   Exception Value: 'module' object is not callable
   ```

Could you please help me find problem with my code?

models.py

```
class ModuleNames(models.Model):
    ModuleName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    ModuleDesc = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    ModuleSort = models.SmallIntegerField()
    isActive = models.BooleanField()
    ModuleType = models.ForeignKey(ModuleTypes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(('ModuleName'), max_length=50, blank=True)

class Meta:
    app_label = 'zz'
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.status
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer
from django.http import HttpResponse
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from django.urls import resolve
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db import connection
from myapp.models import TableDefinition
from myapp.models import ColumnDefinition
from myapp.models import ModuleNames
from myapp.models import ModuleTypes
from collections import namedtuple
from django.db.models import F
import json
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@cache_page(60 * 15)
@csrf_protect
def addmodule(request,moduletype):
    modules=''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.dict()
        data.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken', None)
        for i in data.items():
            obj = ModuleNames.objects.get(id=i[0].split("_")[1])
            print(obj)
            obj.save()
    listmodules = ModuleTypes.objects.get(ModuleType=moduletype)
    modules = ModuleNames.objects.all()
    print(modules)
    return render(request, 'module.html',{'modules' : modules})
```

template.html

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="35px">Id</th> 
            <th width="50px">Module Name</th> 
            <th width="50px">Module Desc</th> 
            <th width="50px">Module Sort</th> 
            <th width="50px">Is Active?</th> 
            <th width="50px">Module Type</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='randomchars'/>

            {% for module in modules %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for="module_id">{{ module.id }} </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="{{ module.id }}" type="text" name="moduleName_{{ module.ModuleName }}" value="{{ module.ModuleName }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="{{ module.id }}" type="text" name="moduleDesc_{{ module.ModuleDesc }}" value="{{ module.ModuleDesc }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="{{ module.id }}" type="text" name="moduleSort_{{ module.ModuleSort }}" value="{{ module.ModuleSort }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="{{ module.id }}" type="text" name="moduleIsActive_{{ module.isActive }}" value="{{ module.isActive }}">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="{{ module.id }}" type="text" name="moduleTypeId_{{ module.ModuleType_id }}" value="{{ module.ModuleType_id }}">
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <!--<input id="module_id" type="text" name="module_id" value="">-->
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="module_name" type="text" name="module_name" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="module_desc" type="text" name="module_desc" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="module_sort" type="text" name="module_sort" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="module_isactive" type="text" name="module_isactive" value="">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="module_typeid" type="text" name="module_typeid" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: could you also show your imports in `views.py` please?

Comment: @RHSmith159 i updated question

Comment: try to remove: 
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='randomchars'/>
and just leave the template tag:{% csrf_token %}

Comment: I did but didn't work. I am also not able to use render in any where of the project

Comment: Can you post the debug traceback (the specific line/s failing)? Also which Django version are you using? Btw, `render_to_response` is failing CSRF because you would need to add the `context_instance` keyword argument: `render_to_response('module.html',{'modules' : modules}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`. It enables the CSRF context processor that inserts the token. BUT `context_instance` was removed in Django 1.10 and `render_to_response` is deprecated after 2.0. [Old docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext)

Comment: I have added traceback in the question.